# Why bottomMargin/topMargin/rightMargin is acting like leftMargin?

Tags: java, android

```
final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);
final ImageView circle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circle);
final ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams screen = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) rl.getLayoutParams();
```

and..

```
        View v;
        v = arrayofImages[i];

        v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            PointF DownPT = new PointF();
            PointF StartPT = new PointF(); 

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int eid = event.getAction();
                switch (eid) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        PointF mv = new PointF(event.getX() - DownPT.x, event.getY() - DownPT.y);
                        v.setX((StartPT.x + mv.x));
                        v.setY( (StartPT.y + mv.y));
                        StartPT = new PointF(v.getX(), v.getY());
                        if (circle.getRight() > v.getX() && circle.getTop() <= v.getY()
                                && circle.getBottom() > v.getY() && circle.getLeft() <= v.getX()) {
                            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                        if (v.getX() > screen.bottomMargin) {
                            v.setX(screen.bottomMargin);
                        }

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        DownPT.x = event.getX();
                        DownPT.y = event.getY();
                        StartPT = new PointF(v.getX(), v.getY());

                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Nothing have to do
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
     });
```

So basically I'm trying to not allow an imageView to go ofscreen. if the view v is going too far left position it on the left side.

```
  if (v.getX() > screen.leftMargin) {
        v.setX(screen.leftMargin);
       }
```

This should do to trick and it does but only for the left margin. If i try something like this

```
   if (v.getX() > screen.rightMargin) {
        v.setX(screen.rightMargin);
       }
```

It acts like it's the leftMargin (it moves my image when i touch it on the left side.)

I don't know what i've done wrong...Please help..If you need more code i will paste but this is all that matters i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are not supposed to be using `bottomMargin` or `topMargin` fields. These are the Margins that you set for the `RelativeLayout`. If you want to check if the `View` doesn't go OUTSIDE the `RelativeLayout`, you need to be checking with `width` and `height`.

But if all you are going to do is to keep the `View` inside the `RelativeLayout`, you need to use `View.getLeft()` and `View.getRight()` instead of `getX()`. This will give the position of the View relative to the parent. You can use this in your logic, rather than using `getX()` (which returns the visual x position of this view, in pixels.)

> It is possible to retrieve the location of a view by invoking the
>   methods getLeft() and getTop(). The former returns the left, or X,
>   coordinate of the rectangle representing the view. The latter returns
>   the top, or Y, coordinate of the rectangle representing the view.
>   These methods both return the location of the view relative to its
>   parent. For instance, when getLeft() returns 20, that means the view
>   is located 20 pixels to the right of the left edge of its direct
>   parent.